# Converting Base64 to Hexadecimal in C

Tags: c, base64, hex

I am trying to make a program that decodes Base64 data to Hexadecimal. Using online tools I can take a Base64 string and convert it to hex as such:

`npswhQDKKfqTEDqDS/b2KcioJdN74tnJJhEeaT2Ds8I=`->`9e9b308500ca29fa93103a834bf6f629c8a825d37be2d9c926111e693d83b3c2`

Does anyone know of any libraries in C that can do this?

Another option I could think of is maybe converting the Base64 text to binary, then from binary to hex, but I would rather no do this if possible.

Comment: You don't need a library, it's easy. Each b64 character represents 6bits, and each hex character 4, so 2 b64 characters can be represented in 3 hex chars. The only tricky bit is dealing with the end when you don't have a multiple of 12 bits encoded.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I dont really understand how this works, do you have any kind of reference as to how this can be implemented. Any language is fine, id just like to see some code of how its done and I can do the translation from one language to another. Are you suggesting I do it using binary?

Comment: I just googled for some examples, but didn't find the killer solution that I wanted to recommend. You can find functions that do this, but rather than copy and paste them, I suggest you write and test your own. Its a good early c programming exercise. One great thing about programming in c is that it allows you to make optimisations specific to your use case. You can optimise for speed, portability, maintainability, space etc, but often not all of them at the same time.

Comment: If you never need the whole encoding in binary, I would take pairs of input characters, make a 12bit integer from them, then output the 3 hex characters it represents using some bitwise shifting operations, and maybe a look-up table or a bunch of 'if's.

Comment: _"id just like to see some code of how its done"_ .. I don't understand what's stopping you. If I type something like `base64 c library` or `base64 code example` into my favorite internet search engine, I get a plethora of hits containing examples, libraries, explanations, _etc_. How exactly are _you_ using the internet?

Comment: Don't agree with this question being closed but this library might do what you need: https://github.com/rafagafe/base64

Btw binary and hexadecimal aren't different datatypes they're just different representations, 'converting' hexadecimal to binary there's no such thing.

I suppose you want to convert it to ASCII, that's a different story, I'd first convert it to binary and then using `sprintf` to convert it to ASCII string.

Comment: @jwielink What's wrong with closing the question? Asking for libraries is [explicitely mentioned as not suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a question at SO. Also, the example given by the OP does not look as if they want to print as ASCII.

Comment: "I would rather no do this if possible" Why not? If you don't want to use enough space for the whole data, you can just take 4 base64-characters and decode to 3 bytes at a time. Then print them and convert the next 4 characters...

Comment: @Gerhardh OP mentioning conversion Base64->binary->hex as an option makes me think they really just want an ASCII string. Otherwise that statement wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @jwielink the OP did not mention ASCII but hex. Where do you derive they want ASCII? Just look at the given example. Clearly hex, not ASCII.

Comment: @Gerhardh I just told you. "Converting" binary to hex, no such thing.